# How to prevent OSX Lion from quitting apps and going to sleep?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion

I'm on Lion 10.7.5 on a Core 2 Duo 21-inch iMac 2008 version, and I've ran both of these from Terminal:

```
defaults write -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool yes
defaults write -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination -int 1
```

I also have both computer sleep and display sleep set to "never" in Energy Saver preferences, and the "put hard disk to sleep when possible" box is also unchecked. I've also downloaded Caffeine from the App store and tried that. Yet, after an hour or so of inactivity, Lion quits all applications, logs out, and goes to sleep. This is frustrating in general, but maddeningly annoying when trying to update Xcode because Lion just kills the update process and goes to sleep. Due to time constraints I can't sit and hold Lion's hand to keep it awake for 5 hours.

Any help appreciated, I dug around a little bit but couldn't find any pertinent questions already answered. Apple Q&A1340 is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `pmset -g` to see the current power management rules that are actually being applied.
- Use `pmset -g sched` to see if someone hasn't helpfully scheduled your computer to shut down at specific times.
- Use `pmset -g activity` and `pmset -g history` to see recent power management activity.
- If that still hasn't shown you what the cause is, you can try `pmset -g everything |more` to look for clues.
- You also might want to look at /var/log/system.log to see if anything was logged just before it went to sleep.

Comment: Problem still unsolved but thank you, this was useful info. The output of `pmset -g` just seemed to confirm that everything which should be false, is, i.e., sleep, disksleep, displaysleep, hibernate are all set to 0.

Comment: Are you plugged into a battery backup via a USB cable? That can tell the system SHUT DOWN NOW. Is it shutting down at specific times (:00 after each hour) or a certain number of minutes after your last activity? Under System Preferences->Sharing is Remote Management turned on? (If so, try turning it off)

Comment: No battery backup, not sure about the specific times but I suspect not, it seems to happen about within a half-hour / hour of inactivity. Remote management unchecked, Bluetooth / Printer sharing both checked. Thanks again for your tenacity!

Comment: Oooh, i know! System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> "Advanced..." (at the bottom, you might have to click the lock to unlock it), then see what "Log out after ___ minutes of inactivity" is set to?

Comment: BINGO! I love you. It was set to logout after 60 minutes. I hope this works because I already got excited and accepted the answer :) Thank you so much, I've only had a few experiences on SO, most of them leave me frustrated, this one has been great. Cheers.

Comment: Awesome, I completely forgot that setting was there until now myself. If for some reason that doesn't work, I'll puzzle on this some more.

Comment: The second you mentioned it, I recalled that I'd checked that like 2 operating systems ago. The setting must have stayed checked during the last two upgrades. I'll come back to confirm tomorrow morning. Here's to hoping to no shutdown overnight!

Answer (score 0):

1) Download [Caffeine](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12&ei=E2uyUOrUJOPmiwKZ_4GYAg&usg=AFQjCNG3ASSwgMLZm2ucpqyoIZbTUIaKJA) from the App Store- it should handle what you're looking for.

2) This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Great observation, username tbd, this is *NOT* a programming question. Why the assumption I didn't read the FAQ? I read it before asking my question. Among other things, it says:

"…if your question generally covers … software tools commonly used by programmers … then you're in the right place to ask your question."

Since my question generally covers Xcode / OSX, which are tools commonly used by programmers, I figured it was fair game, so, can ya relax a little? I'm giving caffeine a try; if it works I'll come back and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No need to get defensive about it, as I wasn't trying to convey an attacking manner- just that SO may not be the best place to ask this question is all. I agree that the App Store (as I believe that's the problem here) and OSX are tools used by programmers, but they're also used by everyone else as well, so I'm not sure if that's the scope the FAQ is looking for. Anyways, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well then petition SO to change their FAQ to suit **your** liking, I was just following what they advise :) Cheers to hoping Caffeine solves the problem.

Comment: it didn't work. I'm sure glad I *DIDN'T* give things the benefit of the doubt. I ended up biting the bullet and holding Lion's hand for 5 hours while Xcode downloaded, and, at least I got the main problem solved. Nonetheless, I can confirm, even with Caffeine, my Mac still sleeps and quits all apps within an hour.

Comment: You're not closing your laptop lid, correct? Caffeine is a popular app used by a pretty large number of people who seem to have no issue with it working, and assuming your iMac is OEM, that's pretty odd indeed.

Comment: From the opening line of my question: "I'm on Lion 10.7.5 on a Core 2 Duo **21-inch iMac** 2008 version."